# Azure Functions - Configure client certificate authentication

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Do functions support authorizing access to a Function by using client certificates, in a **consumption plan**? Something similar to the approach described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth)? Basically, I'm looking for the Functions runtime to immediately reject connection requests if the caller does not present a valid client certificate, without me having to implement that authorization routine in the code.

Comment: You can give it a try and tell us :-)

Comment: We do support that.   Yes, try and let us know.

Comment: @SuwatCh I have problems accessing a function portal blade as soon as I enable this setting.  All works fine until I toggle the client certificate setting - and then the function runtime fails to start and the portal function blade errors.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @SuwatCh I am also having issues with this. Once I turn on the client certificate setting any request to my function fails with an HTTP 401 error. I am trying to use a self signed certificate. Do I need to have a certificate that is signed by a CA?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code I came up with, note: this is for **Azure Functions v1**, when req is an `HttpRequestMessage`

**Caller:**

```cs
X509Certificate2 clientCert = req.GetClientCertificate();

if (!IsValidClientCertificate(clientCert))
{
    return req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "A valid client certificate is not found");
}
```

For **Azure Functions v2**, you can get the client certificate from the `HttpRequest` using `req.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate`

**Basic validation function:**

```cs
static bool IsValidClientCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientCert)
{
    // check the cert's thumbprint against expected thumbprint
    if (clientCert.Thumbprint != "<expected thumprint>"
    { 
        return false;
    }

    // check that we're within the cert's validity period
    if (DateTime.Now > clientCert.NotAfter || DateTime.Now < clientCert.NotBefore)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // optionally check cert chaining validity
    // if(!clientCert.Verify()) { return false; }
}
```

Comment: `HttpRequest` doesn't seem to have a `GetClientCertificate()` method?

Comment: The argument you get in an Azure Function method is of type HttpRequestMessage, which has that method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/http-and-webhooks

Comment: Hmm, yes, I recall it *used* to be, but now you get a `HttpRequest` by default. I seem to seeing a Github issue about this a while back, where a MS employee said this was now their recommendation. I figured out I can get the client cert using `req.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate`

Comment: Ah you're correct, in v1 you get an HttpRequestMessage, in v2 you get an HttpRequest. Nice find on how to get the client cert! I'll update my answer

Answer (score 4):

Based on your requirement, I created my C# HttpTrigger function to check this issue, here is the core code:

```
if(req.Headers.Contains("X-ARR-ClientCert")) 
{   
    byte[] clientCertBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(req.Headers.GetValues("X-ARR-ClientCert").FirstOrDefault());
    var clientCert = new X509Certificate2(clientCertBytes);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"Thumbprint: "+clientCert.Thumbprint);
}
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello world");
```

For App Service Plan, the function could work as follows:

[image]

Per my test, the function could also work as expected under the consumption plan.

You could follow [How To Configure TLS Mutual Authentication for Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth) or just log into Azure Portal and go to your function app, click "NETWORKIING > SSL" under Platform fetures tab, then enable Incoming client certificate option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. If I understand you correctly, you want to reject with a 403, any https requests without a client cert

This is how to enable it with Azure CLI

```
az webapp update --set clientCertEnabled=true --name <app_name> --resource-group <group_name>
```

Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#enable-client-certificates)

You can also do this from the Azure Portal, under Azure Function App => Configuration => General Settings

[image: Enable client Cert]

Comment: For Azure functions, this worked: az functionapp update --set clientCertEnabled=true --name <your function app name> --resource-group <your resource group name>