# mTLS using Azure Function HTTP Trigger?

Tags: python, azure-functions, pyopenssl, mutual-authentication, mtls

I'm working at building an auth token server using a Python Azure Function with HTTP trigger. The goal is to use mutual TLS (mTLS) authentication.

**The way it will work:**

1. Client sends http request to Function endpoint with two headers:

- `requestor-id` : an identifier used for lookups
- `X-ARR-ClientCert` : a string representation of their `.pem` certificate

2. The Function will look in a database where requestor's `.pem` has been previously shared
3. Using `pyOpenSSL`, the Function will load the two `.pem` files and compare the request cert and the retrieved certs:

- `not_valid_before/after` dates
- `common name`
- `issuer`
- `thumbprint`

4. If each property of the certs match, the Function will respond with an auth token for use in a downstream data call

**My question is:**

- This isn't really "mutual" as the server hosting the Function code is not presenting *its* certificate anywhere (visible) in the handshake.
- Is the server side of mTLS handshake configured elsewhere or does it "just work" because the Function endpoint is http**s** out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to  mutual TLS (mTLS) authentication in Azure function app, you just need to enable client certificates. After doing that,  Function App Service injects an `X-ARR-ClientCert` request header with the client certificate. Function  App Service does not do anything with this client certificate other than forwarding it to your app. Your app code is responsible for validating the client certificate. FOr more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#access-client-certificate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686316/azure-functions-configure-client-certificate-authentication)

Comment: Thank you @JimXu. I'm stuck at how to access the `X-ARR-ClientCert` header using Python Function code. There are a few examples of C#, but not one have I found for using Python. Do you know how this header is accessed?

Comment: Disregard. @krishg helped me over [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309694/how-to-decode-x-arr-clientcert-header-using-python)