# How to decode `X-ARR-ClientCert` header using Python?

Tags: python, http-headers, azure-functions, client-certificates, azure-appservice

How do I decode the `X-ARR-ClientCert` header passed by Azure App Service to my Azure Function code?

**Example:**

- HTTP-triggered, Python Azure Function
- Azure App Service configured to accept client certs
- Requestor sends a client certificate with GET request (per [Postman instructions here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/))
- Azure App Service passes client cert to Function code via a `X-ARR-ClientCert` header

**Issue:**

- I cannot find documentation on how this header is encoded
- I cannot find an example of how to decode this header using Python

**The closest I've got is this code:**

```
import logging
import base64
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    
    logging.info('####### Python HTTP trigger certificate validation function processing a request. #######')

    # Retrieve client cert from headers
    req_cert_str = req.headers.get("X-ARR-ClientCert")
    
    req_cert_bytes = base64.b64decode(req_cert_str)
    
    decoded_string = req_cert_bytes.decode('cp1252')

    return func.HttpResponse(
        decoded_string
    )
```

- Which results in `Status 500 Internal server error` and:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.certiFunc <--- Result: Failure Exception: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 403: character maps to <undefined> Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 343, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 480, in __run_sync_func return func(**params) File "/home/site/wwwroot/certiFunc/__init__.py", line 14, in main decoded_string = req_cert_bytes.decode('cp1252') File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/encodings/cp1252.py", line 15, in decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
```

- When substituting `decoded_string = req_cert_bytes.decode('utf-8')`, I get:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.certiFunc <--- Result: Failure Exception: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: invalid start byte Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 343, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 480, in __run_sync_func return func(**params) File "/home/site/wwwroot/certiFunc/__init__.py", line 14, in main decoded_string = req_cert_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```

- When running the following (directly decoding the header)...

```
req_cert_str = req.headers.get("X-ARR-ClientCert")
decoded_string = base64.b64decode(req_cert_str)
```

...I get a `Status 200 Success` but the response is a mashup of binary(?) characters and plain text:

[image]

**What is the correct method for decoding this header using Python?**

**Further reading on the Github issue raised [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1748)**

Comment: Try to load x509 from the bytes (req_cert_bytes)  itself https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/

Comment: I'll try that now. The docs say `Deserialize a certificate from PEM encoded data.` How do I know that `X-ARR-ClientCert` is PEM encoded data? The client uploaded a cert in `.crt` format (as Postman [only currently supports](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/) `.crt.` and `.pfx` formats).

Comment: for `.crt`/`.pfx`, use `load_der_x509_certificate` - Deserialize a certificate from DER encoded data. DER is a binary format and is commonly found in files with the .cer extension (although file extensions are not a guarantee of encoding type).

Comment: Thank you @krishg. `load_der_x509_certificate` says it takes data of type `bytes`. The `X-ARR-ClientCert` header if of type `str`. Do I need to convert first?

Comment: yes, like you were doing `req_cert_str = req.headers.get("X-ARR-ClientCert")
    
    req_cert_bytes = base64.b64decode(req_cert_str)` then pass `req_cert_bytes` to `load_der_x509_certificate`

Comment: There it is! That worked @krishg! Add as an answer and I will mark it as Solution. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked. Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding the client certificate from Postman, it's in DER (binary) format. You can decode the x509 certificate from bytes itself using Python [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/).

```
from cryptography import x509

# header is base64 encoded string, so extract the bytes first
req_cert_str = req.headers.get("X-ARR-ClientCert") 
req_cert_bytes = base64.b64decode(req_cert_str)

cert = x509.load_der_x509_certificate(req_cert_bytes)

# do stuffs with cert
logging.info(f'Received client cert with serial number: {cert.serial_number}')
```

Note: If the certificate was PEM format, you would need to use `x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(req_cert_bytes)`

Comment: Does Azure do any conversion between the client certificate and the `X-ARR-ClientCert` header? **Example:** User sends `.pem` encoded client cert in request. Does Azure convert that to `.der` or will it pass the `.pem`?

Comment: It does not do anything with this client certificate in `X-ARR-ClientCert` header other than forwarding it to your app. Your app code is responsible for validating the client certificate.

Comment: Got it. So if client uploads a `.crt`, it passes a `.crt`; client uploads a `.der`, it passes a `.der` and so on for `.cer` and `.pem` formats as well. Again, thank you @krishg.

Comment: If clients are uploading certs in various formats (.pem, .der, .crt, .cer), how can the cert type be identified using Python?

Comment: I think one simple way is to check the first byte is char '-' in the cert bytes, then its pem format (always has header like `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`), so use `load_pem_x509_certificate`, else use `load_der_x509_certificate` (will cover crt, cer, der). So check first byte from `req_cert_bytes` to decide on which load method to invoke.